# Portable offline password manager

Tags: password-management, keepass

I have an encrypted external hard drive that I want to use as a portable security center.

One of the things I want to do is setup a portable offline password keeper that can run entirely from the external drive. KeePass has a portable version, but since I only run Linux on my devices that is not an option for me.

Are there all-in-one KeePass-like packages that I could put on my external to be able to run on my Linux machines?

Might it just be better to install the program locally and keep the actual password data on the external?

Comment: I would use an open source password manager that can be compiled to a JAR file, which is completely OS independent. This is the most portable option I can think of.

Comment: I would **NOT** do that without the knowledge required to verify that the code is not malicious.

Comment: Product recommendations are off-topic. Apart from that: have you even searched for KeePass and Linux? Because when looking at [keepass.info](http://keepass.info/download.html) you'll find many ports of KeePass, including ports for Linux, for browsers...

Comment: Sorry for being off topic. First post on this forum. And yes I have looked. The problem is that the ports for Linux (AFAIK) have a bunch of dependencies that can feasibly only be satisfied by an OS. Since my external does not have an OS, that's not a good option for me.

Comment: You can statically built the KeePass application so it can run anywhere you need it to run. Or if you're willing to have a bit more infrastructure, you can pack it in a snap/flatpaks or as a docker container (with X sockets forwarded into the container). Alternatively, some password managers like [pass](https://www.passwordstore.org/) is just a bunch of shell script, so you'll only need bash.

Comment: Also note that for KeePass specifically, since it is a .NET/Mono application, the Portable version actually works on Linux as well, provided you have Mono installed on the machine. Refer to [Other Unix-like systems](http://keepass.info/help/v2/setup.html#mono) on how to write a shell script wrapper that runs the Portable version on any systems with Mono.

Comment: I use keepassx on both Debian Gnu/Linux, and when I have to, Microsoft's Windows. The one I use for Microsoft is portable, for Gnu/Linux is was installed with apt. However you could get a statically linked version. Note if your USB ever gets lost and found, then you can not trust it. (at least wipe it, if you are more likely to be attached then wipe it, and get a new one, and never use it again).